# Root cause of ORA-06519

Tags: oracle, plsql, error-handling, transactions

```
Fehler beim Start in Zeile : 1 in Befehl -
DECLARE 
  retval NUMBER;
BEGIN
    MONITORING.PERFORM_CHECK(1000705, retval);
END;
Fehlerbericht -
ORA-06519: Aktive lokale Transaktion erkannt und Rollback durchgeführt
ORA-06512: in "RR_MONITORING.MONITORING_ACTIVITY_LOG", Zeile 13
ORA-06512: in "RR_MONITORING.MONITORING", Zeile 43
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numerischer oder Wertefehler: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: in "RR_MONITORING.MONITORING_ACTIVITY_LOG", Zeile 10
ORA-06512: in "RR_MONITORING.MONITORING", Zeile 259
ORA-06519: Aktive lokale Transaktion erkannt und Rollback durchgeführt
ORA-06512: in "RR_MONITORING.MONITORING_ACTIVITY_LOG", Zeile 13
ORA-06512: in "RR_MONITORING.MONITORING", Zeile 1129
ORA-01422: Exakter Abruf gibt mehr als die angeforderte Zeilenzahl zurück
ORA-06512: in Zeile 4
06519. 00000 -  "active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back"
*Cause:    Before returning from an autonomous PL/SQL block, all autonomous
           transactions started within the block must be completed (either
           committed or rolled back). If not, the active autonomous
           transaction is implicitly rolled back and this error is raised.
*Action:   Ensure that before returning from an autonomous PL/SQL block,
           any active autonomous transactions are explicitly committed
           or rolled back.
```

Which of these error message lines contains the root cause error?
Is it possible that a previous action causes the error or does the error have to be in the code? Is the "character string buffer too small" - error in ACTIVITY_LOG or elsewhere?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "MONITORING_ACTIVITY_LOG" (IN_KPI_DEF_ID_VAL IN VARCHAR DEFAULT 0,IN_OBJECT IN VARCHAR) AS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

err_code VARCHAR(100);
err_msg VARCHAR(200);

BEGIN

    err_code :=SUBSTR(SQLCODE, 1, 100);
    err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
    Insert into ACTIVITY_LOG(KPI_DEF_ID,EXCEPTION_IN,OBJECT,SQL_ERROR_CODE,SQL_ERROR_MESSAGE,TIMESTAMP) VALUES (IN_KPI_DEF_ID_VAL,'MONITORING',IN_OBJECT,err_code,err_msg,SYSDATE);

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like it started with the *"ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"* at line 1129 of `MONITORING.PERFORM_CHECK` (perhaps a `select into`), which triggered a call to the error logger, which itself failed with ORA-06519 due to a missing `commit` for its autonomous transaction.

There also appears to be a *"ORA-06502: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small"* at the `err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);` although it's hard to see why since it's defined as `varchar(200)` (should be `varchar2` by the way). I'm not sure why you would want to truncate it anyway as you may lose useful information. Personally I would use `sqlerrm` directly and ensure the column was adequately sized. (Notice that your actual error stack is 681 bytes long, and truncating it to 200 removes most of the details you are looking for.)

I have never known `sqlcode` to be a useful thing to capture, and I prefer to store the package, procedure, line number, call stack, module, action, client info, user, OS user etc.

Answer (score 3):

ORA-06519 is the root cause of itself. From your trace you have unrelated error messages from other parts of your application, which are triggering the call to `MONITORING_ACTIVITY_LOG`, to log the error messages.

So, ORA-06519. Your procedure declares an AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION `pragma`. The scope of such a transaction is the procedure which declares it. So you need to close the autonomous transaction by issuing a `commit` before the end of the procedure.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  "MONITORING_ACTIVITY_LOG" 
   (IN_KPI_DEF_ID_VAL IN VARCHAR DEFAULT 0,IN_OBJECT IN VARCHAR) 
AS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  err_code VARCHAR(100);
  err_msg VARCHAR(200);    
BEGIN

    err_code :=SUBSTR(SQLCODE, 1, 100);
    err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
    Insert into ACTIVITY_LOG(KPI_DEF_ID,EXCEPTION_IN,OBJECT,SQL_ERROR_CODE,SQL_ERROR_MESSAGE,TIMESTAMP) 
    VALUES (IN_KPI_DEF_ID_VAL,'MONITORING',IN_OBJECT,err_code,err_msg,SYSDATE);
    commit;
END;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only accept one answer as the accepted one, otherwise I would also accept your answer.

Comment: Hmmm. Your question is asking about ORA-06519. My answer addresses that topic, so I would argue that you should accept my answer. Future Seekers finding this thread whilst trying to debug their Autonomous Transaction will be bemused to find the accepted answer doesn't help them.